# Retrieve main class/jar file name passed to the JVM

Tags: java, c++, jvm, jvm-arguments

As a C++ app, is there a way to query a java process(java.exe/javaw.exe) to retrieve the main class or jar file name that was passed to the JVM?
I want the same result as when you run "jps -l":

```
C:\>jps -l -V
2644 sun.tools.jps.Jps
4340 net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.Main
```

I think I could get the command line parameter and try to parse for the class name, but I was wondering if there is simpler method to extract only the class name or jar file name reliably.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Years ago I did submit an RFE to present the main class name as a system propterty. [System property for main class](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4827318). As far as I know there is not a good way to do this without altering the main class (which could be done through instrumentation).

Comment: Link is broken; working link is https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4827318

Answer (score 0):

You might get what you want from [PSAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684884%28VS.85%29.aspx). If you start there, you can navigate to all the other Win32 for dredging information out of processes.